# BizTalk Server 2010 - Can you change the license key?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, license-key

Is there a straight forward way to change the license key for BizTalk? I am speaking specifically about 2010 but info about other versions is welcome as well, if applicable.

The only thing I can think of is to search through the registry, which seems fought with danger.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit cautious here, as far as I know there is no easy way to change it. It's also true if you want to change the BizTalk editions from Enterprise to Developer, etc

Comment: Yes, the client had informed us after an enterprise clustered, with failovers, etc. install that they had given us incorrect license key